# I'm new in R, having trouble with a ggplot code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to finish a course, but one of my ggplot command isnt working and I dont know why.

Here's the chunk code

```
ggplot(data = all_trips_v2, aes(x=started_at)) +
geom_bar() +
facet_wrap(~day_of_week)
```

I appreciate any advice . I really dont know what's wrong.

The plots dont appear in RStudio, and no error is shown either

I tried to search online but it seems the code is right

Comment: A bar chart should have both x-values (normally categories) and y-values (normally numbers).

Comment: Maybe you want geom_hist? NEED DATA!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(all_trips_v2)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(all_trips_v2, 20))`.

Comment: What do you get when you enter `dev.cur()` in your console? From your description, I wonder whether your plots are being sent to somewhere other than RStudio's built-in viewer.